# IPython: How to activate emacs key bindings in Windows?

Tags: windows, ipython, keyboard-shortcuts, command-prompt

If I start IPython in a bash shell, I get emacs shortcuts like Ctrl-k to delete till the end of the line or Ctrl-A to go to the beginning of the line.

But when I start from a dos prompt, I don't have it. How to I activate emacs shortcuts in Windows IPython?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just install [Anaconda](https://anaconda.org/) and start your console with the command:

```
jupyter qtconsole
```

That's the best way to have a productive Python shell in Windows.